# How do I add a bottom bar in ElectronJS like the VSCode one?

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuetify.js

I'm tryin to add a bar at the bottom of my ElectronJS application and I'd like it to be positioned in the same way as the blue bottom bar in VSCode, where the scroll bar ends/stops above it.

[image: vscode_bottom_bar]

Unfortunately, there always seems to be a small space on the right side where the scroll bar would appear when the content overflows (<s>I don't want to disable the scroll bar / behavior with things such as `overflow: hidden;`</s> *See Edit 2*).

[image: space]

I did some testing and with the code below you can see my desired behavior seems to happen with the `nav-drawer`, i.e. its scroll bar stops right above the `v-bottom-navigation`, which would be my bottom bar (the thick grey line you see is the scroll bar).

I'm semi-new to this, but I can't figure out why exactly that happens and how to modify it in order to get the same behavior for the whole application.

[image: scroll_bar]

**VueComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-drawer">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      app
      color="white darken-3"
      mini-variant
      permanent
    >
      <v-avatar
        v-for="n in 30"
        :key="n"
        :color="`grey ${n === 1 ? 'darken' : 'lighten'}-1`"
        size="36"
        class="d-block text-center mx-auto my-3"
      >
        <span>TT</span>
      </v-avatar>
      <v-avatar class="d-block mx-auto">
        <v-btn icon small color="primary">
          <v-icon>fas fa-window-maximize</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-avatar>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-bottom-navigation v-model="value" height="20px" background-color="primary" app>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon small>
        Button
      </v-btn>
    </v-bottom-navigation>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NavDrawer",
  components: {
    //
  },
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
  })
}
</script>
```

P.S. I'm using ElectronJS with VueJS+VuetifyJS - I set it up as described [here](https://itnext.io/electron-application-with-vue-js-and-vuetify-f2a1f9c749b8). Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1:** I went through the VSCode source code and found the UI elements (`vscode/src/vs/base/browser/ui/`). Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out which of those is the bar at the bottom (apparently called `System Bar`, according to some threads I found here and there).

I think it *might* be the `toolbar`, but that seems to be part of the `actionbar`, which is the menu on the left (by default) and doesn't seem to have much `CSS` to indicate that it's the bar at the bottom.

**Edit 2:** I tried adding `html {overflow: hidden;}` in the `style` section of the main `index.html` file. It removes the bar of the main page section (the scrollbar you see in the second picture with the two arrows and green button) and the possibility to scroll, **but** the scrollbar of the `nav-drawer` remains and the scrolling still works. So, I guess this would be an option if I could still have the scrollbar in the main page section with the code above *with* the `hidden` feature enabled as well. Not sure if that's possible though.

**Edit 3:** Using `html {overflow-y: auto;}` in the `index.html` file, removes the scrollbar when there isn't content that is overflowing and it looks just like I want it, **but** when there is, it still taking up space and looks like the the second image in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/frownonline/pen/PLOYMQ)

For my case the solution is adapting the `:root {...}` part to my application, which means to mark the bottom bar as the footer and calculate the content area depending on its size.

The `html {overflow: hidden;}` **must** also be in the `index.html` file's `style` section.